# objective-c complexity reference

Tags: objective-c, complexity-theory

For the c++ STL, there is a [de-facto standard location](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)  (besides the [de-jour standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372), I mean) to find information about the complexity guarantees of standard container operations.

> Is there an analogous, web-accessible document listing complexity guarantees for NSArray, NSDictionary, etc.?

For example, I cannot find a reference that gives complexity for `[NSArray count]`

Comment: Hmm.. STL is a C++ standard. Cocoa is a proprietary framework. I don't think they are comparable. It's closed source so besides documentation, there are no other references.

Comment: @HeShiming; please reread.  This is a question about objective-c, not Cocoa.

Comment: `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` are actually part of `Foundation` framework. However what He Shiming said still holds since it's a Apple framework.

Comment: @Saphrosit gnuStep is open source, isn't it? Suppose he were to look at that for an idea.

Comment: @JRG I'm sorry to mix up Cocoa and Foundation. But Foundation is still proprietary, it's based on objective-c but it's not a part of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct. There isn't one. C++ / the STL (based on my limited understanding) have a significant performance focus. Objective-C / Foundation basically don't.

`NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and friends are interfaces. They tell you how to use them, not how they behave. This gives them the freedom to switch implementation under the hood for performance reasons. The point is, you don't need to care, and this won't be specified in the API so you can't even if you want to ;)

For a really good read on this subject, highlighting implementation switches, and with a rough comparison between Foundation classes and STL / C data structures, check out the Ridiculous Fish (by someone on the Apple AppKit team) [blog post about "Our arrays, aren't"](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html)

Comment: ... and if you read the linked post, it says "The access time for a value in the array is guaranteed to be at worst O(lg N)".  I would like a reference containing similar statements for all objects.

Comment: ..you make a very good point. Having looked through CoreFoundation source, while statements like that exist for `CFArray`, `CFDictionary` etc., I don't believe anything similar exists for Foundation objects, but am now going to go searching some more...

Comment: @KristianGlass: The Foundation objects and the CoreFoundation objects are one and the same. By default, concrete instances of these Foundation classes are implemented by CoreFoundation. Obviously you could create your own subclass that isn't, but normally when you write `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"a", @"1", @"b", @"2", nil]`, it will create a CFDictionary behind the scenes to back the instance.

Comment: @Chuck Ah right, I'd probed no further than seeing the `NSCFDictionary` instances handling Toll-Free Bridging (and alas didn't get far with my search due to life intruding) - thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score -1):

> Is there an analogous, web-accessible document listing complexity
>   guarantees for NSArray, NSDictionary, etc.?

No. If you understand what the different containers do, you'll have a pretty good idea of how they behave (e.g. dictionary == map -> nearly constant-time lookups). But don't assume that you know exactly how these structures behave, because they may [change their behavior based on circumstances](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html). In other words, a class like NSArray may not be (certainly isn't) implemented as an actual array in the sense of a C-style array even though it has that same "ordered sequence of elements" behavior.

You can, of course, analyze the complexity of your own code: your own binary search through an NSArray is always going to take O(log n) operations any way you slice it. Just don't assume that inserting an element into an NSMutableArray is going to require moving all the subsequent elements, because your "array" might really be a linked list or something else.

Comment: Where is it stated that an NSDictionary is a hash map? It could easily be like std::map, which is _typically_ implemented in terms of a red-black tree.  You don't know what's under the hood, but you do know that map::find is O(ln n), map::begin is O(1), etc.

Comment: Are you sure about your statement that binary search in a linked list takes O(ln n)?  I think you might want to consider why std::list does not implement ::find or ::lower_bound.

Comment: @JRG I didn't say that a binary search in a linked list takes O(log n) -- I was talking about analyzing your own code. If you write code that performs a binary search on an NSArray, you can naturally expect it to take log n operations. But those operations are operations on NSArray. So you can know that you'll call `-objectAtIndex:` log n times. That's your own code's complexity. You're not privy to the complexity of `-objectAtIndex:`, and again it may change depending on circumstances. The benefit is code that works better than any single algorithm with no work on your part.

Comment: @JRG I agree that a dictionary may or may not be implemented as a hash map. As with arrays, there may not be a single data structure used in all cases.

Comment: Caleb: I am looking for complexity estimates, i.e. worst-case bounds.  In fact, if NSArray is ever implemented as a linked list as you suggested, objectAtIndex is _not_ O(1) so binary search cannot be O(ln n).